# When any workbook is added or closed to the active workbook the Visibilty status of the application is effected

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Excel 2013 VBA Macro. When any Workbook is added or closed from the Active workbook the **visibilty status** of the application is effected i.e makes Application.visible true.
This causes the workbook visible, hiding the VBA form.
And when I change the Visibility status to false after adding and closing of any other workbook, the whole application visibilty is set to false making the workbook as well as form hidden.

Comment: Could you paste a  snippet of you script? Are you opening additional instances of the `Excel.Application` with your script or are you just opening  or closing additional `WorkBooks`?

Comment: [x-post](http://superuser.com/questions/1004214/excel-2013-vba-macro-when-any-workbook-is-added-or-closed-to-the-active-workbo)

Comment: I am just opening other workbooks with Application.Workbooks.add() for Template or Application.Workbooks.Open() for workbook.Thanks for looking into this.